# Load multiple DNN models in tensorflow and use them multiple times

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have checkpoints of two models of Inception-v3 (.data,.index,.meta files)

I want to load them both into memory in the beginning of the program and use them simultaneously in a while loop.

```
load model1
load model2
while True :
    predict output from model1
    predict output from model2
```

The error I am getting was because I was using the same graph for both the variables. I have added an answer with which I solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the following code I used to solve this.

```
turn_graph = tf.Graph()
posn_graph = tf.Graph()

with turn_graph.as_default():
    from models import inception_v3 as googlenet
    turn_model = googlenet(227,227,3,1.0e-3,output=4)
    turn_model.load('turn_model_01')

with posn_graph.as_default():
    from models import inception_v3 as googlenet
    posn_model = googlenet(227,227,3,1.0e-3,output=4)
    posn_model.load('posn_model_01')

## Other code

while True :
    posn_model.predict([image])
    turn_model.predict([image])
```